# Create array from fetched data and get average

Tags: javascript

I want to show average of population of all the countries.
I am trying to create one array from mapped data and then get average. I don't know how to create one array from the data. Or is there other way of doing it?

code:

```
function getAverage(countries) {
  countries.map((country) => {
    const countryPopulation = country.population;
    console.log(countryPopulation);
    return countryPopulation;
  });
}
```

This it what I get from console.log(countries.population) :
[image: Console.log result]

Comment: `.map` _returns_ the array you’re looking for. Log that result, not the individual `countryPopulation` values. Just look at the examples in the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Answer (score 1):

use `reduce` to sum up all the populations, and divide by the number of countries to get an average. Theres no need to make a separate array to do this.

```
function getAverage(countries) {
  const sum = countries.reduce((acc, country) => acc + country.population,0);
  return sum/countries.length;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an array just to get average, there is a better way of doing it, here is my goto one liner to calculate average of arguments

const average = (...args) => args.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / args.length